# How can I reuse http::response in beast

Tags: c++, boost, beast

I would like to periodically http GET some value from a website.
with beast, the code is like:

```cpp
// Set up an HTTP GET request message
http::request<http::string_body> req{http::verb::get, target, version};
req.set(http::field::host, host);
req.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
http::response<http::string_body> res;
while (true) {
    // Send the HTTP request to the remote host
    http::write(stream, req);
    
    res = {};
    // Receive the HTTP response
    http::read(stream, buffer, res);

    // Write the message to standard out
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
}
```

But in the loop,

```
res = {}
```

brought one temporary object creation, one move/copy assignment and the destroy of the temporary object.
I am wondering if there is a better way to avoid these unnecessary costs。

Comment: Remove `res = {}` and use `http::read(stream, buffer, res, ec);` Then check for errors `if (ec == ...)` and print msg only if no errors occurred. You can also check the return value for number of bytes received. In any case I don't think your code performance will differ if you just leave it like it is.

Comment: remove res={} would cause the *res* accumulate all responses.

Comment: @LongBu that's the worry but it's not actually true: the `read` overload dispatches to an implementation that instaties a parser which does the clear internally: https://i.imgur.com/EJhmp59.png (also posted an answer now, because I think it's a better answer to the question)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the offending line and move the declaration of `res` inside the `while` loop.  `res` will then be created and destroyed each time round the loop:

```
// Set up an HTTP GET request message
http::request<http::string_body> req{http::verb::get, target, version};
req.set(http::field::host, host);
req.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);

while (true) {
    // Send the HTTP request to the remote host
    http::write(stream, req);
    
    // Receive the HTTP response
    http::response<http::string_body> res;
    http::read(stream, buffer, res);

    // Write the message to standard out
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This. Let's the compiler do the optimizations. However, the OP seems to be specifically after a method that avoids re-constructing constituent parts that might e.g. re-use reserved dynamic allocations.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `res = {};` with `res.clear();` or drop it altogether.

The `read` free function instantiates a parser that takes ownership of all response resources (by move)¹. In its constructor, it unconditionally clears the message object anyways:

[image]

You can use a debugger to trace through these lines with a simple tester like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecf1f9402124031d), which is exactly what I did.

---

¹ in the end the message is moved back into the response object passed, so it works out

Comment: the res will accumulate all previous responses with "res.clear" or dropping it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do

```
http::read(stream, buffer, res);
// move the response object to the processing function
process(std::move(res)); // res will be as clean as newly constructed after being moved
```